# jQuery or Javascript to parse querystring on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, parsing, query-string

This form has multiple choices through a checkbox. Eg. Pet You Own is a multiple choice and there are various options such as Cat, Dog, Mule etc.

Now by default, the querystring sent will look like:

```
?pet=dog&pet=cat&pet=mule
```

given all 3 are checked.

I need a way to parse this so that the querystring looks like:

```
?pet=dog,cat,mule
```

Another requirement is that, there are other parameters/inputs in the form so it needs to work in conjunction with other standard form inputs.

Comment: Why don't you use an array ? Name your inputs "pet" to "pets[]".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format you're currently seeing is the conventional format. If your form fields were named `pet[]` rather than `pet`, your server would be able to interpret the result as an array.

Having said that, to actually do what you're requesting, you could reset the `name` attribute of your checkboxes, so that they won't be posted, and instead post a hidden field that holds the value of your checkboxes as a comma separated string:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function() {

    var pets = [];
    $('input[name=pet]:checked').each(function() {
        pets.push($(this).val());
    });

    // stop checkboxes from being posted
    $('input[name=pet]').attr('name','');

    // have an input field be posted instead
    $('#my-hidden-field')
        .val(pets.join(','))
        .attr('name', 'pet');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do this job on server side. When your server receive this request, it will get an array which is called `pet` and has three element: dog,cat and mule. you can conjunction them easily.

====
I implement this with JavaScript:

```
var str = window.location.href;
var queryString = "", temp = {};
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("?") + 1);
str.split("&").some(function(item) {
var tarr = item.split("=");
    if(typeof temp[tarr[0]] == "undefined") {
        temp[tarr[0]] = tarr[1];
    } else if(typeof temp[tarr[0]] == "string") {
        temp[tarr[0]] += "," + tarr[1];
    }
});
// Make queryString
for(var i in temp) {
    queryString += "&" + i + "=" + temp[i];
}
queryString = queryString.replace(/^./,"");

// 
var href = window.location.href;
console.log("before:", href);
href = href.replace(/\?.*$/, "?");
// the url is that you want
console.log("after:", href + queryString);
//window.location.href = href + queryString;
```

OUTPUT:

> before:
>   http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html?pet=dog&pet=cat&pet=mule&animal=camel
>   after:
>   http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html?pet=dog,cat,mule&animal=camel

Answer (score 1):

A bit of cleaning is needed but using this with plain JS you can acheive

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
    var options = "";
    if(document.getElementById("option1").checked){
    options = options+"Milk";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("option2").checked){
    options = options+",Butter";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("option3").checked){
    options = options+",Cheese";
    window.location = "end.html&options="+options
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div align="center"><br>
    <input id="option1" type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
    <input id="option2" type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
    <input id="option3" type="checkbox" name="option3" value="Cheese"> Cheese<br>
    <br>

    </div>
    <a href="#" onClick="myFunction();">Button to submit </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Name your check boxes as p1, p2 etc. Have a hidden field in your form named 'pet'. Just before submit using JS, set the value of your hidden variable the way you need and return true.

```
function beforeSubmit() {
  var p = '';
  if($('#p1').attr('checked')==true) p += ',cat';
  if($('#p2').attr('checked')==true) p += ',dog';
  ...
  p = p.substring(1); // strip the , at 0
  $('#pet').val(p);
  return true;
}
```

and your form should be like:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return beforeSubmit()">
...
<input type="checkbox" name="p1" id="p1">Cat<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="p2" id="p2">Dog<br>
...
<input type="hidden" name="pet" id="pet" value="">
</form>
```